# Displaying a ProgressDialog while Android GL context reloads

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am working on a game that takes a bit of time to reload its textures when the app loses focus. During this time, the app is unresponsive to the user.

I have setup a handler to tell the main Activity class when the textures are done loading so it can hide a ProgressDialog that I start when the user leaves the app as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(final boolean hasWindowFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
    if (hasWindowFocus) {
        if (this.windowLocked && this.gamePaused) {
            this.gamePaused = false;
            Cocos2dxHelper.onResume();
            this.mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
        }
        this.windowLocked = false;
    } else {
        this.windowLocked = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!this.windowLocked && this.gamePaused) {
        this.gamePaused = false;        
        Cocos2dxHelper.onResume();
        this.mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
    }
    if (!this.dialogShowing && this.gamePaused) {
        displayResumingDialog();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    this.gamePaused = true;
    Cocos2dxHelper.onPause();
    this.mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
}
```

The functions to show and hide the dialog look like this:

```
static public void displayResumingDialog() {
    dialogShowing = true;
    resumingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(sContext, "Re-Initializing", "Please Wait...", true);
}

static public void hideResumingDialog() {
    if (resumingDialog != null && resumingDialog.isShowing()) {
        resumingDialog.dismiss();
        dialogShowing = false;
    }
}
```

This works absolutely fine if the user leaves the app via the home button and then comes back by opening the apps drawer and clicking the icon again. If they lock the screen and return, or hold down the home button and return from the list of running apps however, the dialog never gets hidden. In fact, everything except for the dialog stops running. If I setup the dialog to be dismissed when it is touched outside, and I dismiss it, the app is still hung until I press the Back button. Then after a few seconds the textures are reloaded and the game begins.

I've done a fair bit of logging trying to figure it out. All of the calls seem to be the same, except sometimes when the screen is locked, onResume gets called twice. I think my code accounts for that though. If I don't allow it to display when the screen is locked the code run through to the end with no problem. With the dialog up and the screen returns from being locked, the code stops once the dialog shows up so onSurfaceCreated never get called and the textures never have a chance to load. As I said, it doesn't resume until I dismiss the dialog and press the back button.

What would cause the ProgessDialog to completely take over like that? Perhaps more importantly, why does it do it when returning from a locked screen or running apps list but not when clicking on the app icon?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I hate to answer my own question, but I figured out the problem and figured it might help someone else.
The dialog comes into focus when it is created, so the onWindowFocusChanged code never gets called, so the textures never get reloaded. I fixed it by making my dialog not focusable, like so:

```
resumingDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

Although the dialog locks up with the rest of the UI if the user returns from a locked screen at least it is there. I tried showing the dialog in an asynctask to get it to spin while the rest of the UI was locked up, but no such luck. If anyone can tell me how to get the dialog to spin I'd be glad to award the answer to that person. It spins if they come back to the app via the running apps list or the app's icon, just not from a locked screen.